# How to get value of attribute inside an element

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to get an attribute from another element.

E.g.

```
<xsl:template match="tag1">
  Test: <xsl:value-of select="inner[@class='test']@name"/>
</xsl:template>
```

XML:

```
<xml>
  <tag1>
    <inner class="something" name="123"/>
    <inner class="test" name="456"/>
  </tag1>
</xml>
```

So what I'm expecting is to get

```
Test: 456
```

Obviously the XSLT above doesn't work, but that's what it should logically be. Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="inner[@class='test']/@name"/>
```

Just needs a slash in the XPath before @name.